# Need some help diagnosing SEHException External component has thrown an exception

Tags: vb.net, interop, ms-access-2007, oledbconnection

Windows Forms application using VB.Net and VS2012. Connecting to an Access database using Access Runtime 2013.  The app is compiled to target x86.  The problem is intermittent and occurs on multiple different PC's randomly, and accessing a database on a local hard drive.

```
Using cn As New OleDbConnection
  System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor
  If Not OpenDBConnection(cn) Then
      System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default
      MsgBox("Unable to make database connection to update screen status.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Database Connection Error (MMUN1)")
      Exit Sub
  End If
'continue processing....
 end using

Public Function OpenAccessConnection(ByRef conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection) As Boolean
    Dim builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder()

    'conn.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"       
    Try
        builder.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & DPATH & DBNAME
        builder.Add("Provider", "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB." & ACCESSVER & ".0")  'ACCESSVER is '12'
        conn.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor
        conn.Open()
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Unable to make Access connection.  Error# " & Err.Number & " " & ErrorToString() & " " & ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Database Connection Error (OLEOPN1)")
        Return False
    Finally
        builder.Clear()
        builder = Nothing
    End Try
End Function

Public Function OpenDBConnection(ByRef conn As OleDbConnection) As Boolean
'I know this is an extraneous function call but it is in transition from multiple prior uses and I thought I had better not exclude it from this post in case it mattered for some reason
    OpenDBConnection = OpenAccessConnection(conn)
End Function
```

Error being returned intermittently:
[image: SEHException]

I have read many of the posts on this topic and have not found a solution, and frankly am not sure where to look.   Could this be coming from an earlier application error?  Thread/STA issue? If so, what do I do about it?   On the development machine, I will on occasion see a DisconnectedContext error, but have not seen the External component error which appears on PC's running the released version.  Are these related?  Also, there are some ADO (ADODB) connections being made to the database (still trying to replace/upgrade), but these are not open at the time this new connection is being made.  But could it be a connection pooling issue?  Thanks in advance for any help out there.

Comment: Is it possible I need to somehow set a timeout or a retry count?  And would this be a provider property setting, as I don't see a way to do that with the OLEDBCONNECTION itself.  thx

Comment: So following the stack trace, I'm wondering if there is an OLEDB Connection race condition.   Any thoughts on that, or a way to set the retry count?